# .NET 2005 - Testing through IIS runs as x86. Unit Testing runs as x64

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2005, x86, 64-bit

I'm having a bit of a conundrum here.

My dev box is 64bit, windows 7.
All my projects are compiled as "Any CPU".
The project is referencing 64bit versions of 3rd party software

When I run through my unit tests that do not use any web references it works as it should. I can tell it's running as a 64bit process.  I can call my commands, and they work fine.

However, whenever I run a test that invokes a web service call to my own PC, that code comes back telling me it's running as 32bit/x86. The web service is the exact same as the unit tests, but it tests the web service / SOAP proxies, (really it calls the same code, except through a web service).

I've been beating my head for a bit trying to figure this out. I've checked all 3rd party dll's, and ensured they are compiled as 32/64bit, and verified through a quick unit test. I'm not sure why anything through IIS turns it to be 32 bit.

It seems anything going through IIS runs the code as 32bit versus 64 bit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question.  Are you saying that when you talk to the web services hosted on your local IIS your process runs at 32 bit?  Or are you saying that the services hosted in IIS are telling you they are running and 32 bit?

Comment: @mockobject -yes. if I invoke a web service, my code runs as 32bit. If I invoke it directly (the same service start point, or anywhere) it runs as 64bit.

Comment: You shouldn't be invoking a web service as part of a unit test. Mock out the web service call.

Comment: Our black box/system tests will verify a path from start to end which includes multiple service calls. However, a white box/unit test (which for us includes integration tests), performs only 1 of these calls, a simple web service test that also tests white-box code was needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the issue of 32-Bit DLLs that are referenced in AnyCPU compilations for Windows 7 64-Bit causing my app to error. I found that I needed to do the following:

Open IIS > Drill into Application Pools > {your app pool} > Advanced Settings and set the Enable 32-Bit Applications property to True.

Not sure if this is related to your issue specifically or not, but might be something to check out?

Comment: Found it - it was already set to true. going to see how it works if it's false. =D

Comment: It seems that changing it to false works - going to ensure it's working fully.

Comment: Good, seems like it was the other way 'round for you =D

Comment: This is very interesting to me.  I assume that by setting this to false it forced the services to run as 64 bit and would have failed if it tried to call into a 32 bit dll using something like a dllimport.  The things I don't understand: 1) why would the services run at 32 bit if they were capable of running at 64 bit.  2) Why would a service proxy call in a totally separate process that talks to a service hosted in a 32 bit process cause the calling process to run at 32 bit.